# Reciprocal of fp16 in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, half-precision-float

In my OpenCL kernel I use 16bit floating point values of type `half` from the `cl_khr_fp16` extension.

Although this gives me code that works well, I noticed with AMD's radeon developer tools that the reciprocal is computed in 32 bits (gpu target is gfx1102 RDNA3.)

[image: Radeon GPU Analyzer]

So the value is first converted from half precision to single precision, then the reciprocal is computed, and then the result is converted back into half precision.

This is despite having the division with both numerator and denominator in half precision.

I know that CUDA uses a function call for this: [hrcp](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__FUNCTIONS.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__FUNCTIONS_1g3d221a53cabf43e2457ad8ddba3a1278) so I also tried the following OpenCL reciprocal functions [half_recip() / native_recip()](https://man.opencl.org/recip.html) with the same results.

Is there a way to force OpenCL to compute the reciprocal without first converting?

Comment: Did you try ordinary division with a constant 1 as numerator?

Comment: @SimonGoater yes, it is highlighted in the screenshot on the left. It even uses the correct 16b literal.

Comment: Is the type of rad_x half (maybe show/say that)? What are the semantics of (1.0h / ...)? Is there something similar to hrcp (an intrinsic)? I see that AMD does have v_rcp_f16 https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/rdna3-shader-instruction-set-architecture-feb-2023_0.pdf

Comment: What are compile flags?